# Contar cuantos elementos distintos hay en una columna específica

Tags: php, javascript, datatables

Estoy trabajando con DataTables y quería mostrar cuantos elementos distintos contiene una columna de la tabla.Estoy haciendo esto pero no me funciona, directamente no me arroja ningún dato. No sé si estoy haciendo lo correcto.

```
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){

  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "aaSorting": [[7,'desc']],
    "aoColumns": [
                          {"iDataSort": 7},
                          {"bVisible": true},

                          {"bSortable": true},
                          {"bSortable": true},
                          {"bSortable": true},

                          {"bSortable": true},
                          {"bSortable": true},
                          {"bSortable": true},

                          {"bSortable": true},

    ]

} );

var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
var dataCount = oTable.columns(4).data().unique().length;
 $('#routing').text('Número de elementos distintos en esa columna: ' + dataCount);

 });
 </script>
```

Luego lo muestro así:

```
<p id="routing"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Casi lo tenías, utiliza el método `column` para acceder a una columna individual ([más info](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column())). Te pongo un ejemplo (buscando en la columna **Age**):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   
    var oTable = $('#example').DataTable();
var dataCount = oTable.column(3).data().unique().length;
 $('#routing').text('Número de elementos distintos en esa columna: ' + dataCount);

} );
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            
           
           </table>
           
           <p id="routing"></p>
```